# Show that $f(x)=x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is a bijection of $\mathbb R$ onto $\{ y: -1<y<1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

I am looking for help in regard to a practice question about functions. The question is

> Show that a function $f$, defined by $f(x)=x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$ , $x \in \Bbb R$ is a bijection of $\Bbb R$ onto $\{ y: -1<y<1\}$.

So what I know that for it to be a bijection, it must be an injection and also a surjection.
So to proof this question, do I just need to prove both of those?

So for injection, when $x_1=x_2$ $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

To do this I wrote $$\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+1}}=\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+1}},$$ squared both sides and expanded to solve that $x_1=x_2$.

Next for a surjection, must show that the range is contained,

so the bottom cannot be $0$ or negative because cannot square root a negative and cannot divide by $0$.
I believe in this situation you are supposed to write it as $y=x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$ but I have trouble doing that. Or can I jsut do it by solving an inequality such as $\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$,

Comment: You can only square both sides after you check whether or not the sides share the same sign. If you don't do this then you have could prove  $-1 = 1$.

Comment: @user157227, How would I go about checking that?

Comment: Now that I take a closer look, the quantities are equal so they do share the same sign. Nevermind. You did the injection correctly.

Comment: @LearningMath: If $x_1/\sqrt{x_1^2 + 1} = x_2/\sqrt{x_2^2 + 1}$ then $x_1/x_2 = \sqrt{(x_1^2 + 1)/(x_2^2 + 1)}$. Since the RHS is positive, this shows that $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same sign, so now it's valid to square both sides.

Comment: @bungo Oh that is smart, makes sense.

Comment: @LearningMath: user157227's latest comment is correct: if $a=b$ then it's always true that $a^2 = b^2$, so it's unnecessary to check signs in order to square both sides. So by doing that in your case, we get $x_1^2(x_2^2 + 1) = x_2^2(x_1^2 + 1)$, which simplifies to $x_1^2 = x_2^2$. *Now* is when we need to use the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same sign in order to conclude that $x_1 = x_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injective: suppose that
$$\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+1}}=\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+1}}\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Squaring both sides and multiplying out denominators,
$$x_1^2(x_2^2+1)=x_2^2(x_1^2+1)\quad\Rightarrow\quad x_1^2=x_2^2\ .$$
Now substituting back into the denominator on the RHS of $(*)$,
$$\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+1}}=\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+1}}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  x_1=x_2\ .$$
Doing it this way avoids having to (explicitly) consider whether or not $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same sign.

Surjective: we want to solve
$$y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\tag{$*\!*$}$$
for any $y\in(-1,1)$.  Easy algebra gives
$$x^2=\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}\ ,$$
and we now have to consider which square root to take in order to get the right $x$.  It is not hard to see that $y$ should have the same sign as $x$, so we guess
$$x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\ .$$
**Note** the word "guess": if you stop here, the solution is logically backwards and therefore incorrect.  We need to actually substitute this expression for $x$ into the RHS of $(**)$ and confirm that it simplifies to $y$.  This is easy, so I leave it to you.

Comment: "substituting back into the denominator..." to avoid the sign check - nice!

Comment: Very good job,David. You see,it's the little things like these kinds of algebraic shorthand that really help in doing actual mathematics. It really helps avoid subtle confusions that can arise when doing computations by brute force.

Comment: For the surjective part, plugging x into the RHS of (**) does not seem to simplify so easily. I've tried doing it myself and Wolfram Alpha does not seem to simplify it down to y either. Any tips for doing this?

Comment: @samalamma708 $$\eqalign{x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\quad &\Rightarrow\quad x^2+1=\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}+1=\frac{1}{1-y^2}\cr &\Rightarrow\quad \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\bigg/\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=y\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 3):

since $f$ is differentiable
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \frac1{(x^2+1)^{\frac32}}
$$
$f$ is monotonic. but it is also *continuous*...

Comment: So does that show it is surjective?

Comment: have you encountered the intermediate-value theorem?

Comment: Not in analysis, in calculus one though. This seems helpful though.

Comment: Clever,David-but may be a bit subtle for students who aren't strong on calculus beyond simple pencil pushing computations with derivatives and integrals.

Comment: yes, a good point. i failed to identify and address precisely OP's uncertainty

Comment: @DavidHolden Thats alright, thanks for the input. I would still be interested in hearing what you have to say about this? I see that f is differentiable monotonic and continuos, what does this imply?

Comment: monotonic ensures $f$ injective. suppose $f$ not surjective. then $\exists y \in (-1,1). \forall x \in \mathbb{R} f(x) \ne y$. define the open subsets  $U = (-1,y)$ and $V = (y,1)$ then $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$ but also $f^{-1}(U) \cup f^{-1}(V) = \mathbb{R}$. thus $\mathbb{R}$ is disconnected, a contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in (-1, 1)$. Then $y^2 \in (0, 1)$ . That is  $ 0 \lt  y^2 \lt 1 $. Now take,  $$ t = \frac{y^2}{1 - y^2} \implies y^2 = \frac{t}{t + 1} \;\;; \; t\gt 0 \;  \;\text{by its definition }$$

This was inspired by trying to write $y^2$ in the form of $  \dfrac{t}{t + 1}$ and then solving for $t$. Now,

$$ y = \pm \sqrt {\dfrac{t}{t + 1} } = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt t}{ \sqrt{(\sqrt t)^2 + 1}} $$

Now take $x = \sqrt t$ or $ x = - \sqrt t $. Such an $x$ exists in $\Bbb R$ since $t \gt 0$. hence we have proven that there is $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $ y = \dfrac{x}{ \sqrt {x^2 +1}} $

$ \mathscr Q.E.D.$

Ultimately your $x$ is equal to $ \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{y^2}{1 - y^2}} $

Answer (score 1):

I am starting with known facts

$\displaystyle\sin:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to (-1,1) $ and $\displaystyle\tan:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to \mathbb{R}$ $\;$ are bijective

For One one:

Choose $\tan(x),\tan(y)\in \mathbb{R}$ with $x,y\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

then $\displaystyle f(\tan(x))=f(\tan(y))\Rightarrow\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}}=\frac{\tan y}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 y}}$

$\Rightarrow \sin x=\sin y\iff x=y\iff\tan x=\tan y \;$

for every $\displaystyle x,y\in\left(-\frac{\pi}
{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Now for onto:

for every $a\in (-1,1) $ we can find $\displaystyle\theta\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $a=\sin\theta$

There exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(b)=a $ where $b=\tan\theta$

Since $a\text{ and } b$ are arbitrary

Hence $\forall \; y\in(-1,1)\;\exists \;x\in\mathbb{R}\text{such that }f(x)=y$

we are done